# Style System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox to not display selectedItem

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I am creating a comboBox in c# to handle a list. Please look into the picture.

[my picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aimMX.png)

What I want is to make the selectedItem not to display after I select any item.

The desired outcome will be like this:
[expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xNtCL.png).
Furthermore, if can make it to display like a button, that will be better.

Any idea how to do so?

Simple example: V is the toggleButton

Original:

```
selectedItem | V
 item1
 item2
 item3
```

What I want:

```
V
 item1
 item2
 item3
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17737988/wpf-button-with-drop-down-list-and-arrow

Comment: @ASh I want comboBox, not this

Comment: "Furthermore, if can make it to display like a button, that will be better." - you contradict yourself

Comment: @ASh because the comboBox has a toggle button itself, I wonder if can remove the selectedItemContainer, then remain only the toggle button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to edit a ControlTemplate for your ComboBox and reference it either directly or throught style for your ComboBox:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/combobox-styles-and-templates?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

You can remove the ContentPreseter named ContentSite, and all refernces to it in triggers and storyboards.

In the ComboBoxItem you will have to remove triggers/storyboard that work when its IsSelected is true.